# Use an sql "CONVERT" stored procedure in a Magento collection

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to add a "CONVERT" stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT id, value, CONVERT(value, DECIMAL) AS ordred_value FROM test ORDER BY ordred_value;
```

to this collection query :

```
$collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
    ->addAttributeToSort('my_attribute', 'DESC');
```

for the purpose of ordering the associated products by my custom attribute "my_attribute" that have numeric values in text fields.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the bast solution, but you can do it like this:

```
<?php

$collection->getSelct()->columns(array('converted_value' => 'CONVERT(e.my_attribute, DECIMAL)'));
```

It will add a new column to result. Next sort the collection using it's select as above and the `order` method.

Comment: Thank you vsushkov, in getSelect, you have forgotton an "e"; I have this corrected, but I get errors, can you please review the code once more. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have tried the generated request directly in phpmyadmin, but I get this error : #1054 - Unknown column 'e.my_attribute' in 'field list'
How can I correct that ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Before my code snippet echo the select query: echo `$collection->getSelect(); die;` You will see the query generated by Magento. Find the alias which is used in FROM condition. Instead of `e.my_attribute` in the CONVERT condition use the _alias_from_FROM_condition.name_of_your_attribute. If it will not help, will be useful if you post somewhere here the query you got.

Comment: I haven't understand the alias things; here is my query:
SELECT `e`.*, IF(_table_status.value_id>0, _table_status.value, _table_status_default.value) AS `status`, IFNULL(`my_attribute_option_value_t2`.`value`, `my_attribute_option_value_t1`.`value`) AS `my_attribute_value`, CONVERT(e.my_attribute, DECIMAL) AS `converted_value`, `links`.`link_id`, `link_attribute_position_int`.`value` AS `position`, `link_attribute_qty_decimal`.`value` AS `qty` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON

Comment: product_website.product_id=e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id='1' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_status_default` ON (_table_status_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (_table_status_default.attribute_id='84') AND _table_status_default.store_id=0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_status` ON (_table_status.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (_table_status.attribute_id='84') AND (_table_status.store_id='1') LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `my_attribute_t1` ON `e`.`entity_id`=`my_attribute_t1`.`entity_id` AND `my_attribute_t1`.`attribute_id`='138'

Comment: AND `my_attribute_t1`.`store_id`='0' LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `my_attribute_t2` ON `e`.`entity_id`=`my_attribute_t2`.`entity_id` AND `my_attribute_t2`.`attribute_id`='138' AND `my_attribute_t2`.`store_id`='1' LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `my_attribute_option_value_t1` ON `my_attribute_option_value_t1`.`option_id`=IF(`my_attribute_t2`.`value_id`>0, `my_attribute_t2`.`value`, `my_attribute_t1`.`value`) AND `my_attribute_option_value_t1`.`store_id`='0' LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `my_attribute_option_value_t2` ON

Comment: `my_attribute_option_value_t2`.`option_id`=IF(`my_attribute_t2`.`value_id`>0, `my_attribute_t2`.`value`, `my_attribute_t1`.`value`) AND `my_attribute_option_value_t1`.`store_id`='1' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 3 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` AS `link_attribute_position_int` ON link_attribute_position_int.link_id=links.link_id AND link_attribute_position_int.product_link_attribute_id=7 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal` AS

Comment: `link_attribute_qty_decimal` ON link_attribute_qty_decimal.link_id=links.link_id AND link_attribute_qty_decimal.product_link_attribute_id=8 WHERE (((e.required_options != '1') or (e.required_options is NULL))) AND (IF(_table_status.value_id>0, _table_status.value, _table_status_default.value) in (1)) AND (links.product_id = '12441') AND (e.entity_id != '12441') ORDER BY `position` asc, `my_attribute_value` DESC

Comment: OK. I have what you need =) `$collection->getSelect()->columns('ordered_value' => 'CONVERT(IFNULL(my_attribute_option_value_t2.value, my_attribute_option_value_t1.value) ,DECIMAL)')->order('ordered_value DESC');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4227/discussion-between-vsushkov-and-bizboss)